# Copying event handlers from one set of elements to another one using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following

```
 var $header = $('.inner th');
 var $fixedHeader = $(".header1 th");

    $header.each(function (index) {
          // i need to copy all events from $header[index] to $fixedHeader[index]
    });
```

How do I copy the event handlers (onClick, onDblClick..etc) from elements in the first set to the adjacent elements in the second set?? I am novice to jquery and having hard time.

Comment: What do you mean by "events"?

Comment: Ah, OK. You mean _event handlers_.

Comment: do you want to copy elements or events?

Comment: @AtesGoral Yes Event Handlers, I updated the question.

Comment: Editing the title would also help draw a properly directed audience. I've done it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jquery's [.data('events')](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method.

I've provided a working jsFiddle to get an idea of where to start.

http://jsfiddle.net/hx8gf/2/

I know Alphamale beat me, but I'm still going to post it incase it's helpful.

*it's almost identical anyway...*

Comment: For some reason @AlphaMale 's code didn't work. yours did just fine. I added the code you posted in jsFiddle in the answer.. thanks mate.

Answer (score 5):

I know this has already been answered a few times, but here is an all inclusive solution, based on the previous solutions.

```
function copyEvents(source, destination) {
    var events;

    //copying from one to one or more
    source = $(source).first();
    destination = $(destination);

    //get all the events from the source
    events = $(source).data('events');
    if (!events) return;

    //make copies of all events for each destination
    destination.each(function() {
        var t = $(this);
        $.each(events, function(index, event) {
            $.each(event, function(i, v) {
                t.bind(v.type, v.handler);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like this may help:

```
var header = $('.inner th');
var fixedHeader = $(".header1 th");

header.each(function (index) {

    var events = $(header).data("events"); //Gives you all events of an element

    $.each(events, function(i, event) { //Loop through all the events

     $.each(event, function(j, h) { //Loop through all the handlers attached for a event

      fixedHeader.bind(i, h.handler); //Bind the handler with the event 

     });

    });

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: fixedHeader.bind(i, h.handler); This line binds all eventhandlers of header to fixed header. does'nt it?!

Comment: +1 for the code. eventhu i didnt work i know it will work if its someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

The clone(true) function in jquery can not copy event handling, but it can only copy element.If you want to copy it, it is about to add an event binding. You can have a look at the event binding of JQUERY. Call the binding function in the callback function. this may help.

Comment: I have been reading for hours and couldn't.. the whole jquery thing is not `binding` to my brain!