# Replace text inside an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm needing to replace a portion of text inside arbitrary elements. I won't know anything about the structure of the element, including about any child elements it may have, but I have to assume there may be child elements with attached bindings. An example might be:

```
<div id="checkit">
  Lorem ipsum textum checkum.
  <input type="button" id="clickit" value="Click Me" />
</div>
```

Now, if I want to replace 'ipsum' with something else, I could grab the contents of #checkit with innerHTML, run replace on it, then set its innerHTML with the new text, but if a binding has been set on #clickit, the binding will be lost when innerHTML is updated.

I don't really need or want to replace the entire innerHTML of the element but I'm not sure how else to replace a portion of text in the element.

So my question is twofold:

1. Suggestion on how to replace a portion of text within #checkit
2. Suggestion on how to replace innerHTML without losing bindings (or a way to save bindings inside #checkit and reapply them after replacing innerHTML)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Suggestion on how to replace a portion of text within #checkit

You can use this way t replace only the text content without disturbing any element inside of it.

```
$('#checkit').contents().each(function(){
    if(this.nodeType===3) //select only the text nodes
    {
      this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/u/g,'Z'); //replace all u with z
    }
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VunwW/)

> Suggestion on how to replace innerHTML without losing bindings (or a way to save bindings inside #checkit and reapply them after replacing innerHTML)?

If you want to replace innerHTML and keep the binding intact, you may bind the event again or use event delegation using `.on()` in jquery. so that event is attached to the elements present in the DOM now as well as for the future, that matches the selector, without having to bind them again.

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Unfortunately, .on() didn't work quite that way for me; even setting a binding using .on(), it was still lost when innerHTML changed. Besides that, I'm dealing with arbitrary content that has bindings set by other people so I can't control how they are set.

Comment: the nodeValue tip gave me what I was looking for, though, so thank you!

Comment: @ChrisRoberts for your first comment if you can provide a sample example i can take a look. on should work. probably your selector might have caused an issue.

Comment: Another follow-up question. This answer worked in my code - with one problem I should have realized from the nodetype. I'm trying to wrap the text in a tag. So for instance where I once had lipsum I now have '<span>lipsum</span>'. It works - but displays as text rather than markup.

Comment: For the wrapping thing you can refere to my another answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803704/find-and-wrap-every-instance-of-a-text-character-in-a-span-using-jquery/16803822#16803822

Comment: For your event issue this is the way to use `on` for dynamic element http://jsfiddle.net/XzmzD/

Comment: Appreciate the wrapping answer, but that goes back to the earlier issue - replacing with html() strips any bindings, and I can't guarantee that bindings have been set in a way that will persevere through being replaced.

Comment: @ChrisRoberts CHeck this answer to copy over events to another element. You can do this before replacement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222143/copying-event-handlers-from-one-set-of-elements-to-another-one-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks for another good answer, but either I'm doing it wrong, or it looks like that doesn't work if the original data is removed. It's fine for copying bindings, but not saving bindings. When I try to re-set the bindings after changing 'html()', nothing happens. I'm guessing because of what the jquery docs say: "jQuery ensures that the data is removed when DOM elements are removed via jQuery methods" I think I'll just back up and try a completely different approach to what I'm ultimately trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve the problem is just add the text inside another element and find the previous element using prev() method of Jquery ....

You can check the link :

http://api.jquery.com/prev

HTML CODE :

```
<div id="checkit">
    <div >Lorem ipsum textum checkum.</div>
  <input type="button" id="clickit" value="Click Me" />
</div>
```

JQUERY CODE :

```
$ = jQuery.noConflict();
$("#checkit").delegate('#clickit' , 'click' , function(){
   $(this).prev().html('your text here..');
});
```

And code is also created on the jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/paragkuhikar/VxJBD/

Please check it...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't really work inside arbitrary content when the text I'm trying to match may not actually be previous to the trigger.